# Pass parameter from webform to webservice in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

My friend ahs created an ASP.net C# based webservice which takes a parameter - ProjectNumber and returns set of data. I want to consume this webservice in my VB.net project. So I added the webservice as a webreferdence to my vb project as below:

[image]

My default.aspx looks as below:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Trial application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                   <div>
            <p>enter project numbers:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="402px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

On button click I want to pass textbox value as parameter to the webservice:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim projectId As String
        projectId = TextBox1.ToString()
        Dim GetProjectDetails As GetProjDetails = New GetProjDetails 'GetProjDetails-webreference name
        Dim result = GetProjectDetails.projdet(projectId)'Getprojdet is the method inside the webservice
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub
```

But I am seeing "type expected" error with this. Not sure how to fix. Any help?!

Comment: First of all, comments in vb.net don't start with //. They start with '

Comment: Just added them here for clarity sake

Comment: What type of parameter is 'projdet' expecting? Do you have Option Explicit and Option Strict on for this project?

Comment: projectid is a string entry (like p1001,p1002..)

Comment: is this one correct--> Dim GetProjectDetails As GetProjDetails = New GetProjDetails

Comment: `GetProjDetails` might be the namespace. Use ObjectBrowser (ctl-alt-j) to see if there are any classes within `GetProjDetails`.